# BigQuery Set column name with variable

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to set column name with variable (or with SELECT query). I tried below which does not work.

```
DECLARE colname STRING DEFAULT "name";

SELECT "value" as colname
```

Returns wrong column name (**colname** instead of **name**):

| colname |
| --- |
| value |

and

```
DECLARE colname STRING DEFAULT "name";
    
SELECT "value" as (SELECT colname);
```

Returns Error

Neither worked. Is there any way to do this?

The result should be:

| name |
| --- |
| value |

I have a bigger problem, that I want to solve with this.

Comment: Check this out - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare

Comment: Can you post a bigger problem, maybe there is a better way to handle it.

Comment: Try this ````DECLARE colname STRING DEFAULT "name";

execute immediate "select 'value' as "|| colname````

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Batra your solution works. You can write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```sql
DECLARE colname STRING DEFAULT "name"; 
execute immediate "select 'value' as "|| colname
```